# Tensorflow: either input labels or feature vector seem to be in wrong shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am getting started with TensorFlow 2.0 currently and I just read about the estimator class.

I created a simple XOR generator that gives me 2D coordinates (numpy array) and a label.

The data gets standardized correctly, everything works just fine until the 40th line, at that point I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 2 elements to shape [2,2] (4
>   elements) for '{{node
>   dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/X_1/Reshape}} =
>   Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   Tshape=DT_INT32](dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/X_1/ExpandDims,
>   dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/X_1/Reshape/shape)' with
>   input shapes: [2,1], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial
>   shapes: input[1] = [2,2].

This doesn't make sense to me as I checked my input shape, it is indeed, as specified, (2,) and the label is a scalar tensor:

```
({'X': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([ 0.2885114 , -0.77485602])>}, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.0>)
```

The code is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import XorGenerator as XOR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as SC

@tf.function
def trainingData(X, y, batchSize=1):
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.uint8)
    y = tf.one_hot(y, depth=2, on_value=1, off_value=0)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'data' : X}, y))
    #dataset.batch(batchSize)

    return dataset.repeat()

def main():
    X, y = XOR.XOR(400)     # X: float 2D-coordinates, y: class labels (-1 and 1)

    y = np.where(y == -1, np.zeros(shape=y.shape), y)   # labels from (-1 and 1) to (0 and 1)

    sc = SC(with_mean=True, with_std=True)
    X = sc.fit_transform(X)

    BATCH_SIZE = 1
    EPOCHS = 10
    N_SAMPLES = 400

    inputFeatureColumns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='data', shape=(2))]

    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[32, 16], feature_columns=inputFeatureColumns, n_classes=2, 
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid, optimizer='SGD')
    estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: trainingData(X, y, BATCH_SIZE), steps=EPOCHS * N_SAMPLES / BATCH_SIZE)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

XorGenerator:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sign(x):
    return 1 if x > 0 else -1

def XOR(nSamples):
    resX = [np.random.random(size=2) * 2 - 1 for _ in range(nSamples)]
    resY = [np.random.random(size=2) * 2 - 1 for _ in range(nSamples)]

    for x in range(nSamples):
        resY[x] = sign(resX[x][0] * resX[x][1])

    return np.array(resX), np.array(resY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your model has shape `2`, as `n_classes=2`, and your label is of shape `1` , as per `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.0>`. When computing your loss, you need to subtract those two vectors, which you can't do as they have different shapes. You should **convert your label to a one hot encoding** using `tf.one_hot`.

EDIT:
try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as SC

@tf.function
def trainingData(X0, X1, y, batchSize=1):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'data0' : X0, 'data1':X1}, y))
    return dataset.repeat()

def main():
    X, y = np.asarray([[1.0,2.5] for i in range(200)]), np.asarray([1 for i in range(200)])
    y = np.expand_dims(np.asarray(np.where(y == -1, np.zeros(shape=y.shape), y)),1)  
    sc = SC(with_mean=True, with_std=True)
    X = sc.fit_transform(X)
    BATCH_SIZE = 1
    EPOCHS = 10
    N_SAMPLES = 400

    inputFeatureColumns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='data0', shape=(1,)), tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='data1', shape=(1,))]

    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[32, 16], feature_columns=inputFeatureColumns, n_classes=2, 
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid, optimizer='SGD')
    estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: trainingData(np.expand_dims(X[:,0],1),np.expand_dims(X[:,1],1), y, BATCH_SIZE), steps=EPOCHS * N_SAMPLES / BATCH_SIZE)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I couldn't install `XorGenerator` so you still have to change some things. It runs, but I'm not sure it does what you want.

Comment: even though your explanation seems totally logical, I unfortunately still get the same error.

Comment: Hmm. Can you update your code? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train says that you can just provide the `Dataset` object, no need to wrap it in a `lambda`. Does removing the `lambda` help?

Comment: I literally did nothing but encoding y to one-hot with depth=2.

Comment: I needed to add the tensorflow.function decorator to my trainingData(X, y, batchSize) function, but now I get a different error: "No unary variant device copy function found for direction: 1 and Variant type_index: class tensorflow::data::`anonymous namespace'::DatasetVariantWrapper". I guess, I should just revert the changes back to the lambda implementation.

Comment: just updated the code, simplified it a bit. Still the same.

Comment: Also, the book I read to learn machine learning, the lambda-approach is also used.

Comment: could you please explain, why you added the numpy.expand_dims(...,1)? Does it have something to do with hot tensors are composed? With expand_dims() it now works on my original code, too.